# Unable to download mod_wsgi using pip

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

Unable to download mod_wsgi using pip install

Getting the below error-

100% |################################| 499kB 379kB/s
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\z003nsbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8lso5mlc\mod-wsgi\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\z003nsbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r5xt3gnf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

```
running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-3.4

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi

copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server

copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server

copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server

copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server\management

copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server\management

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands

copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands

copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\docs

copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\docs

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\images

copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\images

copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.4\mod_wsgi\images

running build_ext

building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\z003nsbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-8lso5mlc\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\z003nsbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r5xt3gnf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\z003nsbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8lso5mlc\mod-wsgi
```

Getting error code 1

Comment: You can download and install prepackaged binaries for current versions of Python: [mod_wsgi](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi). For the old Python 3.4 you will have to install Visual Studio and then use your way again..

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have Visual Studio installed on your Computer?
2. Run the same command from Visual studio developer prompt ( preferably after opening it as administrator). Read about visual studio command prompt here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs

Comment: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat ??

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\z003nsbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tyf5aes6\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\z003nsbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tyf5aes6\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)

Comment: Was able to fix this issue after installing build tools for microsoft visual C++

Comment: may be edit the title of the post to [Solved] and add your observation to its content.

Comment: so that others might benefit from from it.